# Error when pass "enum" in a function with variable arguments

Tags: c, arguments

I'm reading the book Head First C and I am the part about the variable arguments.

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

enum drink {
    MUDSLIDE, FUZZY_NAVEL, MONKEY_GLAND, ZOMBIE
};

double price(enum drink d) {
    switch(d) {
    case MUDSLIDE:
        return 6.79;
    case FUZZY_NAVEL:
        return 5.31;
    case MONKEY_GLAND:
        return 4.82;
    case ZOMBIE:
        return 5.89;
    }
    return 0;
}

double calc(int args, ...) {
    double total = 0;

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, args);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < args; i++) {
        int currentDrink = va_arg(ap, int);
        total += price((drink) currentDrink);
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return total;
}

int main() {
    printf("Price is %.2f\n", calc(2, MONKEY_GLAND, MUDSLIDE));
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and works perfectly.

But... There are two different lines of my solution with the book.

**My:**

```
int currentDrink = va_arg(ap, int);
total += price((drink) currentDrink);
```

**Book:**

```
enum drink currentDrink = va_arg(ap, enum drink);
total += price(currentDrink);
```

I tried to use the solution proposed in the book, but the error during execution and reports a warning: *'drink' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...'*

The book is used gcc compiler on linux. I am using gcc on Windows.

Question: What is the reason I was unable to compile the code proposed in the book?

**Edit**
There configured wrong. Was using a C++ compiler was thinking of using a C. 
But the question remains: why in C++ results in a warning and error in the execution?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. The book version works fine for me. What version of gcc are you using? Run `gcc --version`.

Comment: Please provide your version information for your compiler.  Also, for the sake of style and simplicity, try using this for your enum definition: `typedef enum drink {
    MUDSLIDE, FUZZY_NAVEL, MONKEY_GLAND, ZOMBIE
} drink;`. That way, you can just use `drink` as a type, rather than having to type `enum drink`.

Comment: @ooga gcc (tdm-1) 4.5.2

Comment: This seems to be a discrepance between C and C++. Compiling as C worked perfectly, while compiling as C++ shows your warning. Make sure you are compiling as C (by making sure the file has a .c extension). Can somebody find a source in the standard for this, or is it really a compiler problem?

Comment: @Dogbert I did what you suggested, but remained the same.

Comment: @Anthales I'm using CodeBlocks. When creating the project, I chose "C", the file extension is ".c". Should I check something else?

Comment: @KeplerBR In Codeblocks, check the properties of your .c file -> Advanced -> Compiler Variable. It should be "CC".

Comment: @KelperBR (I'm too slow to edit..) Also make sure you set up your compiler correctly: Settings -> Compiler... -> Toolchain executable -> C Compiler: This should be <whatever>gcc.exe (probably mingw32-gcc.exe), not <whatever>g++.exe.

Comment: @Anthales The error was that. Was with "g+ +", while the correct would be "gcc". 
Maybe I changed to compile another project and then forgot.

Comment: Rereading your question, I'm a little confused: For gcc, a warning means that it nevertheless compiles, but in your question at the bottom you say, you'd been unable to compile; did you get just a warning or did it not compile at all?

Comment: @mafso He compiled as C++, and g++ tells you the following: warning: 'drink' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' [enabled by default]|
note: (so you should pass 'int' not 'drink' to 'va_arg')|
note: if this code is reached, the program will abort| So it compiles, but the program 'gracefully crashes'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variadic arguments to functions are subject to a conversion called *default argument promotions*: Everything with a conversion rank smaller than that of `int` gets promoted to `int` before passed to a variadic function. And an `enum` has a smaller conversion rank (and may be represented as a `short` or something else in your case). So what your callee sees is an int and must fetch it by `va_arg` as such.

C99 7.15.1.1 p.2 (emphasis mine) about `va_arg`:

> […] If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (*as promoted according to the default argument promotions*), the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - [sth. about pointer types]

And 6.7.2.2, p.4:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, […]

So, the `va_arg(ap, enum drink)` version has no defined bahavior (as far as the C standard is concerned). At least, if the compiler doesn't specify to always use `int` for `enum`s. Hence the warning from `gcc`.

Some coding-guidelines say to avoid `enum` usage for types entirely, using `int` everywhere and only define `enum` constants:

```
enum {
    MUDSLIDE, FUZZY_NAVEL, MONKEY_GLAND, ZOMBIE
};
```

and

```
double price(int d);
```

HTH

Comment: Your answer is confusing me. When you talk about "his version", you mean the one where he uses `va_arg(ap, int)`. By argument promotion the passed `enum drink` will be promoted to `int`, therefore this macro call will be correct. In the book version, `va_arg(ap, enum drink)` is used and §6.7.2.2 says that `enum drink` is compatible with `int` (which is the actual (promoted) type of the argument), therefore you cannot say that it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Anthales: I did it the wrong way round… Fixed, thanks. And no, as I understand it, it says they are incompatible (if the compiler don't use `int` for the `enum`).

Comment: I believe you are right. Although enum constants are of type `int`, the enum type itself can, depending on the platform, be compatible only to `char`, therefore `va_arg(ap, enum drink)` would pull too few bytes. Therefore the book is wrong and you have to do something like `(enum drink)va_arg(ap, int)`.

Comment: I read and reread several times the response and comments. I was confused, but I think that is what I needed - maybe something I have not learned.
For what reason it is not recommended to pass "enum" in arguments?

Comment: @KeplerBR This is basically your answer: The book version is no well-defined C (it is platform dependent; only correct if your enum type is implemented with `int` type); It is also no well-defined C++ (C++ Working Draft N3242, §7.2 p.6 basically says the same as §6.7.2.2 p.4). I guess the reason the C++ compiler gives a warning while the C compiler doesn't is simply because the C compiler historically is far less complex - because that way, it can be maintained much easier. Such a warning could be seen as clutter and there are specific code analysis programs, so "it's not really needed".

Comment: @KeplerBR The problem of enum types is that their underlying types are not clearly defined. It could be a `char`, a `short`, an `unsigned short`, etc. In certain situations, to be more precise, situations where the size of the type counts, it can be a hassle to use enum types. Basically everything that uses `sizeof x`, where `x` is/has an enumeration type is likely an error. `va_args` is an example of a macro which uses `sizeof`, and breaks because of the vagueness of enum types. Personally, I wouldn't discourage use of enum types, as long as it adds readability (but there is also `typedef`).

Comment: @Anthales: Thanks for the pointers to the C++ standard (I'm bad at finding things there…); [The gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation) says, that the underlying type may be specified by the ABI. On what platform did you compile? I don't get a warning when compiling as C++ (with g++ version 4.4.5 on an Intel x86 64-bit with GNU/Linux). Maybe the ABI specifies something for some architecture differently for C and C++ (sounds somewhat unikely, though)?

Comment: @mafso I compiled on Win7x64, using TDM-GCC-64 4.8.1-3 (so it's basically gcc/g++ 4.8.1). Strangely, I didn't find anything relevant in the (Itanium  C++) ABI, but the link you sent says: _Normally, the [underlying] type [of an enum type] is `unsigned int` (...)._ and on my platform it indeed uses `unsigned int`. So the warning (which causes the program to abort) seems to completely ignore the actual enum type parameter of `va_args` (tested, even when enum uses `(signed) int`) - which is a good thing, because it is bad code. You'll probably get the warning using a newer gcc version, too.

Comment: Sorry for the excavation, @Anthales, just in case your interested: I think I see the difference between C and C++ now: In C, `enum` are compatible with some implementation-defined type (for gcc: `unsigned int`), in C++, they are a distinct type, being promoted to the first of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, ..., so the `enum` is _never_ a type which can be fetched by `va_arg`; in C, it is valid as long the underlying type is not smaller than `int`.

Comment: @mafso: I think you are right! After some search I found [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Prototypes.html): "(...) [the] argument’s type must be self-promoting: that is, the default promotions must not change its type. (...) This is actually an ISO C requirement.". While this is about C, C++ is compatible with C variadic functions (it actually refers to the ISO C standard). So the difference here is that `enum` types in C _can be_ self-promoting, but in C++ they never can. That's probably the reason g++ has a default warning and even aborts the program.

Comment: `enum`s may even be wider than `int` by default…