# How to pass (enum types type, ...) to another function that require (enum types type, ...)?

Tags: c, arguments

I have two functions and I'm trying call in the first function that require "(enum types type, ...)" to the second that also require "(enum types type, ...)" passing the "va_list args" of the first function to the second, see:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum types {
  String, Integer, Double, Float = Double,
  End
};

void fn1(enum types type, va_list args);
void fn2(enum types type, ...);

int main() {
  fn1(Integer, 3);
  return 0;
}

void fn1(enum types type, va_list args) {
  va_list argsCopy;
  va_copy(argsCopy, args);
  fn2(type, &argsCopy);
  va_end(argsCopy);
}

void fn2(enum types type, ...) {
  va_list args;
  int count;
  va_start(args, type);
  count = 0;
  while (type != End) {
    switch (type) {
    case String:
      fprintf(stdout, "char arg[%d]: %s\n", count, va_arg(args, const char *));
      break;
    case Integer:
      fprintf(stdout, "int arg[%d]: %d\n", count, va_arg(args, int));
      break;
    case Double:
      fprintf(stdout, "double arg[%d]: %f\n", count, va_arg(args, double));
      break;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "unknown type specifier\n");
      break;
    }
    type = va_arg(args, enum types);
    count++;
    }
  va_end(args);
}
```

I got:

```
Segmentation fault
```

So I tried with this [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048892/8211088):

```
#ifdef HAVE_VA_LIST_AS_ARRAY
#define MAKE_POINTER_FROM_VA_LIST_ARG(arg) ((va_list *)(arg))
#else
#define MAKE_POINTER_FROM_VA_LIST_ARG(arg) (&(arg))
#endif

//...

void fn1(enum types type, va_list args) {
  fn2(type, MAKE_POINTER_FROM_VA_LIST_ARG(args));
}

//...
```

and I got:

```
int arg[0]: 571263040
unknown type specifier
unknown type specifier
char arg[3]: UHåAWAVAUATSHì(L%X¸
```

So, What the way to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: You're doing it totally wrong. `va_start` is used in a function that ends with `...`. And is passed to a function that takes `va_list`.

Comment: You also never use a value of `End` so your loop will try to access arguments that don't exist.

Comment: Just avoid variadic functions. It's a dangerous and superfluous feature, which mainly serves as a source of bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand vararg functions.

The `fn2` function should invoke `va_start`, and then call `fn1` with the `va_list`.

And your code should then call `fn2` instead. And you must remember to add the `End` enumeration at the end of the argument list.

So your code should be:

```
fn2(Integer, 123, End);
```

And then `fn2` should be something like:

```
void fn2(enum types type, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, type);
    fn1(type, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

And finally put your loop and printing in the `fn1` function:

```
void fn1(enum types type, va_list args)
{
    while (type != End)
    {
        // ...
        type = va_arg(args, enum types);
    }
}
```

Comment: 6.4.4.3.2. "An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type int.". While enumeration type may be char,int or unsigned according to 6.7.2.2.4. therefore it is unsafe to use enums in 'va_arg()'

Comment: It! Now It's working. But I don't changed the names like you did, I need fn2 called in fn1, so, I change the arguments and call the fn1 with end. If you change the names I think that solution is more clear, It small detail. Thanks.

Comment: @tstanisl but I didn't use enumeration type, I only called the enum of "type". So, It safe yet.

Comment: @PerduGames, please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/24580800/4989451

Comment: @tstanisl Ok, thanks! I changed the parameters "enum types type" to "int type".